# Ruby on Rails between :text text:?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

In Ruby on Rails, what is the difference between

```
:bonus_card
```

and

```
dependent: ?
```

(in the example

```
class TrainPassengers < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :bonus_card, dependent: :destroy
end
```

)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dependent: :destroy
```

is alternate syntax for:

```
:dependent => :destroy
```

It's [new in Ruby 1.9](http://nuclearsquid.com/writings/ruby-1-9-what-s-new-what-s-changed/#new-stuff-in-ruby-19).

`:dependent`, `:destroy` and `:bonus_card` are all [symbols](http://www.robertsosinski.com/2009/01/11/the-difference-between-ruby-symbols-and-strings/).

Answer (score 0):

it is new syntax in ruby 1.9

```
   dependent: :destroy
```

which is alternative of this

```
  :dependent => :destroy
```

i think you are new in ruby because experienced person has idea about it and if you scaffold then   dependent: :destroy this code is generated by rails by default now.

:dependent ,:destroy and :bonus_card are all symbols.Read about symbols these are very usefull

Answer (score 0):

In Ruby, `:something` is a symbol. A symbol is a reference kept in memory and looked up quickly, so that it is a nice data type to use as hash keys. A Ruby Hash usually looks like:

```
{ :some_key => "some data", :other_key => 65536, :yet_another_key => :symbol_as_data }
```

Ruby 1.9 introduced a shorthand notation for writing the above, as long as keys are symbols, you can move the colon to the end and omit the fat arrow `=>`

```
{ some_key: "some data", other_key: 65536, yet_another_key: :symbol_as_data }
```

This is only valid for symbols passed as hash **keys** (also in hashes passed as method parameters). Other objects used as hash keys must still use the fat arrow(`=>`), and symbols used elsewhere are always written colon-first.